# Have 2 one to one relationships between the same models

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a User model & a Sale model. A User can be either a Merchant or Customer.

When a sale is made the sale belongs to a merchant but also to a customer.

I figured I can give the sale a merchant_id & a sale_id and create 2 different relationships in the models.

Just didn't feel right to me. So my question is there a better way to go about this? I'm in a early stage of development. I wouldn't mind changing the database around a bit.

I'm using laravel 5.3

Comment: Can you show your table schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not one-to-one, it's [many-to-many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relationship and `sales` table should be a pivot table. Relation usually looks like this:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function customers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'sales', 'customer_id', 'merchant_id');
    }
```

Where `customer_id` and `merchant_id` are foreign keys pointed to `id` in `users` table.

If you do a lot of stuff with `sales` table, just keep using `Sale` model for this pivot table.

Comment: Didn't think of using sales as a pivot table! thanks, great solution.

Comment: It is mostly about getting the sale from a merchant or customer. or the other way around. not moving from merchant to customer.

Wont this just move me past the sales table every time?

Comment: I want to be able to say things like, User->sale and get the sale. Or from the sale->customer or sale->merchant.
Now when I would call sales on user I would be presented with the other user connected by the sale.

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, then you need to create and use at least to relations in `User` model (i.e `customers` and `clients`). If you're gonna to work with pivot table a lot, maybe it's better to use model for it (i.e. `Sale`) and get customer with simple `Sale::where('id', $saleId)->first()->customer_id;` or create a sale with `Sale::create(['customer_id => $customer_id, 'merchant_id' => $merchand_id, 'status' => 1]);` etc.